# Active Symbol Highlighting with SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2015 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, highlight, symbols, specflow

I have installed SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2015 and I am finding that Active Symbol Highlighting under cursor no longer works for me in feature files. It works fine in C# files but not SpecFlow files. This came in handy with large feature files in Visual Studio 2013 before I upgraded. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by 'Active symbol highlighting' could you expand on exactly what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

The Active Symbol Highlighting is a feature of Visual Studio with the Specflow extensions/plugin. (Goto Tools ->Extensions->Online and search for Specflow.)

Once it is installed it shows the Feature Files (Gherkins) syntax in blue, implemented steps in black, unimplemented steps in purple, variables in grey, etc.

I was in the similar situation with one of my projects, in all the others the syntax highlighting works. I just asked some one else and it works for them so it must be my Visual Studio storing the projects highlighting settings somewhere.

As with a lot Visual Studio project issues deleting the project .suo file fixed it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: "deleting the project .suo file fixed it." this looks like a answer to me

Comment: This worked magically, got my gherkin syntax highlighter back in Visual Studio 2015 Professional edition